# How to scroll to top (or anchor) from current position on view change with AngularJS?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, scroll

I am about to start to learn Angular and I just wanted to know if it is possible to make it so that after scrolling down and a link is clicked to change the view, how would you make it so that when the next view gets loaded in the scroll position will animate scrolling up to the top of the page (or an anchor point) from its current location instead of just jumping to the top of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll) service , See the example in documentation ,

```
    <a id="top"></a>

   $location.hash('top');
   $anchorScroll();
```